# Jquery animation wont work after stoping it twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little problem. I have made a color animation but when i stop it, and start it again `newClass` disappears. When i stop it again `newClass1` disappears and then app won't start again. I have searched the web but can't find anything. 
Thanks for helping me out.

```
        //Html
           <section class="effect">
           enter code here</section>
           <section class="button">
           <button id="button-start" value="run animasjon">Start animasjon</button>
           <button id="button-stop" value="Stop animasjon">Stop Animasjon</button>
        </section>

             //JS        
             $(document).ready(function(){

        var state = true;

          $("#button-start").click(function colorAnimasjon(){
              $(".effect").addClass("newClass", 1000, "linear", function en(){
          "linear", colorAnimasjon);});         

                     $(".effect").removeClass("newClass", 1000, "linear",function to(){
                       $(".effect").addClass("newClass1", 1000, "linear", function tre(){

                           $(".effect").removeClass("newClass1", 1000 "linear", colorAnimasjon);});                                      


                            $(".effect").removeClass("newClass1", 1000 "linear", colorAnimasjon);});                                                                                                                                        


                  $( "#button-stop").click(function() {
          $( ".effect" ).stop();
            });     
           });
        });
        }); 
      });
```

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle?

Comment: "fiddle" refers to: http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Okay i will give it a try=)

Comment: For some reson i cant start the app in jsfiddle. Im new to the program so not sure hvae to add in jquery script. But here is the code like i have it on mye computer. Mybe u can try run it if you got time. http://jsfiddle.net/CPw4C/2/ . thx for helping